# File Not Upload Error parse_save_from_excel Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, uploadify, spreadsheet

i'm try to get https://github.com/jalagrange/excel_test_app/

but file not upload. i'm trying to fix the following error message

```
Errno::EBADF (Bad file descriptor - C:/Sites/ExcelTestApp/public/excel_uploaded_
files/contacts.xls):
  app/controllers/people_controller.rb:129:in `parse_save_from_excel'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:19:in `call'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:19:in `call'
```

people_controler.rb

```
def parse_save_from_excel
    test_file = params[:excel_file]
    file = FileUploader.new
    file.store!(test_file)
    book = Spreadsheet.open "#{file.store_path}"
    sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
    @people = []
    sheet1.each 1 do |row|
      p = Person.new
      p.first_name = row[0]
      p.last_name = row[1]
      p.age = row[2]
      @people << p
    end
    file.remove!
  end
```

but, I dont understand...

flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
    @app = app
    @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ @session_key,
                             req.params[@session_key] ]
                           .join('=').freeze unless req.params[@session_key].nil?
      env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "#{req.params['_http_accept']}"
                           .freeze unless req.params['_http_accept'].nil?
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```